# Display issue with ext js components when added dynamically at runtime

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs

I am creating layout with ExtJs components and need to add widgets dynamically at run time. The code adds three containers to **viewport**, **top**, left and **center tab panel**. The tab panel further contains two tabs (Ex.panel.Panel) and the second tab contains an **html Editor**.

Code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
 var vp = Ext.create("Ext.container.Viewport", {
     layout: 'border'
 });

 var top = Ext.create("Ext.container.Container", {
     renderTo: 'top',
     height: 70,
     region: 'north'
 });
 var left = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
     renderTo: 'left',
     title: 'Menu',
     split: true,
     collapsible: true,
     width: 270,
     region: 'west'
 });
 var center = Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
     renderTo: 'center',
     region: 'center',
 });

 vp.add(top);
 vp.add(left);
 vp.add(center);

 var tab1 = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
     renderTo: "tab1",
     layout: "fit",
     title: "Tab-1"
 });
 var tab2 = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
     renderTo: "tab2",
     layout: "fit",
     title: "Tab-2: Editor"
 });

 center.add(tab1);
 center.add(tab2);

 var editor = Ext.create("Ext.form.HtmlEditor", {
     renderTo: "editor"
 });

 tab2.add(editor);

 //center.doLayout();
});
```

**The problem is that the editor is not displayed within second tab instead it displays on top. However when I click on second tab then it automatically corrects the layout and display html editor at correct position. But still the html editor does not allow to type.**

Furthermore, I have observed that the documentation does not include examples of creating layout at run time, all examples demonstrate design time creation of layouts.

I also tried **TabPanel.doLayout()** method after adding tabs and html editor but still it does not correct the display issue. Please share if there is any idea on how to add components dynamically in ExtJs.

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uZGxS/

Comment: I'd suggest you read the docs about `render`/`renderTo`, specifically about when NOT to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the tab issues. While adding new tab to tab panel if we set it active then the child components will render correctly. In this case now the html editor layout renders and displays at correct position.

```
center.add(tab1);
center.setActiveTab(tab1);
center.add(tab2);
center.setActiveTab(tab2);
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/uZGxS/1/